# How to Using ASIHTTPRequest to tracking Upload/Download progress

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, asihttprequest, uiprogressview

I got some question is using ASIHTTPRequest to tracking Upload/Download progress

This is the sample from ASIHTTPRequest website

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:myProgressIndicator];
[request startSynchronous];
NSLog(@"Max: %f, Value: %f", [myProgressIndicator maxValue],[myProgressIndicator doubleValue]
```

It says :***myProgressIndicator* is an NSProgressIndicator.**

But it looks like Apple deprecated **NSProgressIndicator**

[Check Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSProgressIndicator_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

So ... how can I know the Upload/Download progress ???

Also another question is ...if the Upload/Download was terminated before the task finish

How can I let the Upload/Download task continues start from the stop point(break point?) ?

Many thanks ~

Comment: `NSProgressIndicator` is a Mac class but you've tagged your question `iphone` and `ios`. Which platform are you developing for? Also, `NSProgressIndicator` has not been deprecated. A couple of methods have been but the class as a whole is still there.

Comment: sorry,I didn't tag the question clearly ,I was develop on iphone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the documentation says, the delegate can also be an UIProgressView in case of iphone/ipad:

> Each ASIHTTPRequest has two delegates
>   that can be used for tracking progress
>   - downloadProgressDelegate (for downloads) and uploadProgressDelegate
>   (for uploads).
>
> Progress delegates can be
>   **NSProgressIndicators** (Mac OS X) or
>   **UIProgressViews** (iPhone).
>   ASIHTTPRequest will automatically
>   cater for the differences in the
>   behaviour of these two classes. If you
>   want, you can also use a custom class
>   as a progress delegate, as long as it
>   responds to setProgress:.
>
> - If you are performing a single
>     request, you set an upload and/or
>     download progress delegate on that
>     request
> - If you are performing multiple
>     requests in a queue, and you want to
>     track overall progress for all
>     requests in the queue, use a
>     ASINetworkQueue and set the progress
>     delegate of the queue
> - If you want to
>     do both of these at the same time,
>     this is possible too (as of v0.97)

source: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#tracking_progress

Answer (score 1):

Only certain methods of NSProgressView are deprecated. Specifically `-animate`, `-animationDelay`, and `-setAnimationDelay`. They changed how you use the class, they didn't deprecate the whole class.

Also, with the tags you chose for your question, you probably want `UIProgressView`, which is the iPhone version.

Comment: yes ,I was develop on iphone version ,can you give some sample about using UIProgressView to track up/download ? thank you