# ASIHTTPRequest tracking download progress doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, asihttprequest

I'm using ASIHTTPRequest to track downloading but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm using the code shown in: [How to Using ASIHTTPRequest to tracking Upload/Download progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602812/how-to-using-asihttprequest-to-tracking-upload-download-progress), but Xcode errors out saying `maxValue cannot be found`.

Then I tried:

```
UIProgressView * myProgressIndicator;
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:myProgressIndicator];
[request startSynchronous];
NSLog(@"Value: %f", [myProgressIndicator progress];
```

This failed as well. Can someone help?

Comment: FYI ASIRequest is not anymore supported. I advice to use something else. Regarding you question what do you expect to see?

Comment: Thanks @Nekto, actually I want to use UIAlertView and UIProgressView to let user know the downloading status, but i cannot get values 'maxValue' and 'doubleValue' given by [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602812/how-to-using-asihttprequest-to-tracking-upload-download-progress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code from the ASIHttpRequest website you're referring to is for a Mac application, not an iOS app.  In the example code the delegate object is an instance of `NSProgressIndicator`, but that class is not available in iOS.  Instead, when using ASIHttpRequest in iOS the delegate object should be a `UIProgressView` instance.

UIProgressView does not have maxValue or a doubleValue properties.  UIProgressView instead has a `progress` property, which is a float that can take values between 0.0 (0% complete) and 1.0 (100% complete).

You can learn more about the `UIProgressView` class [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thx @jonkroll , but I try code `UIProgressView * myProgressIndicator;
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:myProgressIndicator];
[request startSynchronous];
NSLog(@"Value: %f", [myProgressIndicator progress];` as I writen before, there is also no log be displayed, so why?

Comment: In that code you are declaring a `UIProgressView` local variable but you are not instantiating an object anywhere, so `myProgressIndicator` is null.