# HTTP PUT method how to track the upload progress

Tags: ios, http, asihttprequest, progress, put

I am using HTTP PUT method to upload the video file with ASIHttpRequest, but the progress tracking is not working. The following methods only called 2 times (started and finished).

```
- (void)setProgress:(float)newProgress;
```

If it is POST upload, it works fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602812/how-to-using-asihttprequest-to-tracking-upload-download-progress

Comment: If it is POST upload, it works fine.