# How to find percentage of image upload to server using NSMutableURLRequest request

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, asihttprequest, uiprogressbar

I am sending image to server using NSMutableURLRequest Request(using Api call), I am sending each image at a time, can I find the percentage of image uploading to server, if so how can u please the code for that , and with that percentage i even want to update progress Bar.

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602812/how-to-using-asihttprequest-to-tracking-upload-download-progress http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#tracking_progress

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tutorial for getting progress and displaying it [How-to-use progress](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#tracking_progress)

Hope it helps you.